# How do I know if my instance connection is correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs, aws-cloud9

I am trying to load a model into EFS. I followed all the steps in the tutorial  [Mounting on Amazon EC2 Linux instances using the EFS mount helper.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-helper-ec2-linux.html) to do the EFS mount.

I managed to mount the EFS and connect to my instance, however, something is looking strange, I am entering all the commands at once and have to wait for the connection to finish.

[image]

How do I know if my instance connection is correct on ***cloud9***? Because I was expecting that my commands would be executed line by line.

When my connection terminates instead of having my model in the ***ml*** directory, I get my model in the ***efs*** directory, I tried to do `cd ml` before  `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket-ml-models-1026/linear_model.zip .`, but it didn't work, the result I get is the following:

[image]

What must I do to download my file into the ***ml*** folder?

Comment: did you try to perform this from your local machine?

Comment: No, I create an Amazon ECE instance via cloud9 and try to connect via SSH and I was able to do the mount, my problem is that the EFS and the EC2 instance was with different security groups, plus I had to edit the inbound and outbound of this security group.